# Regex to replace ampersands, but not when they're in a URL

Tags: html, regex, encoding, ampersand

So I have this regex:

```
&(?!#?[xX]?(?:[0-9a-fA-F]+|\w+);)
```

That matches all &'s in a block of text

However, if I have this string:

```
& & & & & <a href="http://localhost/MyFile.aspx?mything=2&this=4">My Text &</a>
---------------------------------------------------------^
```

... the marked & also get's targeted - and as I'm using it to replace the &'s with & the url then becomes invalid:

```
http://localhost/MyFile.aspx?mything=2&amp;this=4
```

D'oh!  Does anyone know of a better way of encoding &'s that are **not** in a url.

Comment: `\w` already matches all characters in the class `[0-9a-fA-F]`. So `(?:[0-9a-fA-F]+|\w+)` can simply be written as `\w+`.

Comment: Your code sample is invalid. You **should** encode the ampersands in URLs: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp

Comment: I think that's a little harsh.  I'll pick any website at random now and I promise you that I will not find in the source: <a href="http://example.com/mypage.html?one=1&amp;two=2">My Link</a>...so because I was unware of this fact I'm being downvoted?!  At least write it as an answer so everyone else who didn't know this can find out!

Comment: "You shouldn't ask this question" isn't, IMO, an answer, so I'm not going to mark it as such. Guffa feels otherwise. (And I think you're putting way too much value on points.)

Comment: I'm not - I just feel a bit "told off" that my question is invalid - whereas in fact it was a valid question as far as I was aware.  A valid answer, IMO, is that in fact what I'm trying to do isn't neccessary, so don't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the URL does not become invalid. The HTML code becomes:

```
<a href="http://localhost/MyFile.aspx?mything=2&amp;this=4">
```

This means that the code that was not correctly encoded now is correctly encoded, and the actual URL that the link contains is:

```
http://localhost/MyFile.aspx?mything=2&this=4
```

So, it's not a problem that the & character in the code gets encoded, on the contrary the code is now correct.

Comment: While most browsers can error correct if the attribute includes &this=, trying it with &copy= will demonstrate that this is a real issue and that attributes containing URIs are not exceptions to the rules for encoding characters which have special meaning in HTML.

Comment: What source? The raw source? Then the HTML to represent the URL would be &amp;amp;. 

Or do you think that the OP has some content which has the href attributes HTML encoded, but not the rest of the content? Because that would be **very** odd.

Comment: @cletus: Then the URL is not correctly encoded, and that can't be solved by any HTML encoding. The & character in the value has to be encoded as %26, or the URL will not work either with or without HTML encoding.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell this could be done as:

```
$String ='& & & & & <a href="http://localhost/MyFile.aspx?mything=2&this=4">My Text &</a>'
$String -replace '(?<!<[^<>]*)&', "&amp;"
```

yields

```
&amp; &amp; &amp; &amp; &amp; <a href="http://localhost/MyFile.aspx?mything=2&this=4">My Text &amp;</a>
```

Dissecting the regex:

1. The look around (?<! .... ) first validates that you're not in any tag
2. All & strings are then found and replaced.